# Is there a SQL regex function that can separate Emojis from other non-ASCII characters?

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I have a table in SQL that contains text data, and sometimes that text data contains emojis. See below for sample table output:

| CommentID | Comment_Text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A walk in the park. |
| 2 | A lovely day in the park |
| 3 | A sunny day in the park |

What I'd like to do is separate out the emoji as a column. Ultimately what I'd like to end up with is a binary column indicating whether the comment text contains an emoji.

After some research, I was able to find the following solution:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(Comment_Text, '[^\x00-\x7F]+', 1, 1)
```

Which will separate out the first emoji the code finds. In actuality, this regex doesn't find emojis, it just finds non-ASCII characters - emojis just happen to fall in that category. While this solution does work sometimes, it does not work when there are emojis **and** non-ASCII characters in the same comment. So, for example, if the comment was 'A lovely walk in the πaÞk ', the code would output both the emojis but also the π and the Þ.

What I need is a way to separate out the emojis from the other non-ASCII characters.

Comment: First, you will have to define what exactly makes a character an emoji.

Answer (score 2):

Good day sir.
Can you try this function on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XgIdMm/1) site?
I think it will work.

[^\x00-\x7F]+[^x00-\x7F]